# no match for 'operator<=' in 'i <= slovo'

Tags: c++

here is my code, im getting error  no match for 'operator<=' in 'i <= slovo' 
its a program which converts word in each row from capitals to lowercase...

can u help with this?? thanks

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    const int max = 100;
    string slovo;
    int pocet_r;

    cout << "Zadaj pocet uloh:" << endl;
    cin >> pocet_r;

    if(pocet_r >= 1 && pocet_r <=100)
 {

     // funkcia na zabezpecenie minimalneho poctu chars
          for (int i = 0; i <pocet_r; i++)
     {
           cout << "Uloha " << i+1 << ":" << endl; 

                cin >> slovo;

                if(slovo.size() > max)
                {
                 cout << "slovo musi mat minimalne 1 a maximalne 100 znakov" << endl;
                }
                 while( slovo.size() > max) 
                 {
                  cin >> slovo;
                 }      
     }
     for (int i=0; i <= slovo; i++)
            {
                while (slovo[i] >= 'A' && slovo[i] <= 'Z')
                {
                      slovo[i] = tolower(slovo[i]);
                      }
            }       

 }else{
     cout << "Minimalne 1 a maximalne 100 uloh" << endl;
}
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `slovo` is a `string`, `i` is an `int`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i <= slovo` tries to compare an integer to a string. With our mighty human brains, we know that `42` is acually larger than `"This string"`, but the compiler isn't as smart, so it just doesn't let you compare integers to strings.

Did you mean to compare `i` to the string's length (i.e. `.length()` or `.size()`)?

```
for (int i=0; i <= slovo.size(); i++)
//               |
// You probably want < here though, not <=
```

Comment: thanks, that works, I totally forgot about it :D and I have one more question, I want to add a _ in front of every Capital letter which will be converted to lowercase, plus the first letter cant have the _, cause string cant start with _... same for the last letter in a string... I cant figure out how to do it... :{  example: input: LoL, output: lo_l

Answer (score 2):

`slovo` is a string, so `i <= slovo` doesn't make sense.

Did you mean to say `i <= slovo.length()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `i <= slove.size()` instead of `i <= slove()`.